# very slow to get specific rows in scipy csr_matrix and use sparse.vstack to combine them

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm learning machine learning and I have two tables, the first one is the training set which includes a column named "userID".
The other table is the App feature of each user(the apps each user have) and was transformed as csr_matrix which looks like(in dense form):

```
[[0,1,...0,1],[1,0,...,1,1],[0,0,...0,0]...]
```

some of the row in csr_matrix are all zeros element. For each userID in first table, I construct the app feature by getting the corresponding row from the feature matrix and vstack one by one.

```
index = userMap[userID] # the userMap contains {userID: index},index is the row index in csr_matrix
userAppfeat = sparse.vstack((userAppfeat,App_csr_Matrix.getrow(index)))
```

It's very slow to add a row to the existing userAppfeat. It is because of the getrow() or the vstack()?  Or i guess it's some rows that contains all zero element cause this.
 and another strange thing is that for the first 100k users it used 5 mins but for the second 100k users it used 20 mins.

Comment: Why aren't you collecting rows for all UserID with one indexing operation?  Iterative array build is slow with dense arrays and slower still with sparse.

Comment: @hpaulj really thank you! I was so wrong that I thought the indexing operation is also achieved by getrow and stack one by one.

Comment: For one row `getrow` is as good as indexing, even a bit faster.  The problem is with doing it one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's been noted many times that building a dense array iteratively is slow.  Doing a `concatenate` at each step creates a new array each time. It is better to collect values in a list, and do one array creation at the end.

Sparse matrix iteration is even slower.  `getrow` creates a new (1,n) csr matrix; `vstack` constructs a new matrix from the components, using the `coo` attributes.

```
In [74]: M=sparse.rand(100,100,.2,'csr')
In [75]: idx=np.random.randint(0,100,50)
In [76]: 
    ...: target = sparse.csr_matrix((0,100))
    ...: for i in idx:
    ...:    target=sparse.vstack([target, M.getrow(i)])
    ...: 
In [77]: target
Out[77]: 
<50x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 944 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

But we don't have to iterate.  `M` accepts a list of row indices.

```
In [78]: M[idx,:]
Out[78]: 
<50x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 944 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [79]: 
In [79]: %%timeit
    ...: target = sparse.csr_matrix((0,100))
    ...: for i in idx:
    ...:    target=sparse.vstack([target, M.getrow(i)])
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 10.4 ms per loop
In [80]: 
In [80]: timeit M[idx,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop
```

The `M[idx,:]` actually constructs an `extractor` matrix, `p`, and performs a matrix multiplication, `p*M`.  `csr` matrices are optimized for multiplication tasks.

Iterative but with delayed vstack:

```
In [94]: %%timeit
    ...: target = []
    ...: for i in idx: target.append(M.getrow(i))
    ...: target = sparse.vstack(target)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.63 ms per loop
```

Comment: `csr` row indexing is still much much slower (like 30x slower) than dense array row indexing, isn't it?